# Unable to find simple memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Can someone please help me find the memory leak which is occurring here? I am just attempting to load a 1600x960 24bit RAW image (46,08,000 bytes) into memory using an Image class I designed. In memory its taking 30MB, as I see in task manager..

Even after the destructor is called (going out of scope) it still takes up 2M. Please help!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

struct pixel {
    char* color;  // to support various BPP
};

class Image
{
    private:
        pixel** image;
        int     width;
        int     height;
        int     BPP;    // bytes per pixel
        int     size;   // in bytes

    public:
        Image(std::string src, int width, int height, int BPP);
        ~Image();
        pixel** get_matrix(int col, int row, int BPP);
};

pixel** Image :: get_matrix(int col, int row, int BPP)
{
            pixel** matrix = new pixel*[row];
            for(int i=0 ; i<row ; i++)
            {
                matrix[i] = new pixel[col];
                for(int j=0 ; j<col ; j++)
                    matrix[i][j].color = new char[BPP];
            }
            return matrix;
}

Image :: Image(std::string src, int width, int height, int BPP)
{
    FILE *in;
    if( (in = fopen(src.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL )
        image = NULL;
    else
    {
        this->height = height;
        this->width  = width;
        this->BPP    = BPP;
        this->size   = width*BPP*height;

        image = get_matrix(width,height,BPP);
        char* buffer = new char[size];
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, in);

        int l=0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0 ; k<BPP ; k++)
                    image[i][j].color[k] = buffer[l++];
            }
        }
        delete []buffer;
        fclose(in);
    }
}

Image :: ~Image()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++)
            delete []image[i][j].color;
        delete []image[i];
    }
    delete []image;
}

int main()
{
    {
        getchar();
        Image in("x.raw", 1600, 960, 3);
        getchar();
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure this is a memory leak? What tool are you using? 2) You could omit the file I/O, initialize the colors to {0,0,0} and simplify things.

Comment: @Beta I am using Codeblocks on Win7, using Process Explorer to see memory usage. I'll try what you said

Comment: I don't see any leak, either. If you are working on the class anyway, you should pass the string argument to the constructor as a reference, i.e. `const std::string& src`. Right now you are making an unnecessary copy. I mention this because passing copies instead of references can quickly become a bad habit.

Comment: `Can someone please help me find the memory leak which is occurring here?` No. This is a Q&A not a debugging crowdsource site.

Comment: I can help you fix the leak: use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not spot a memory leak there, but the program is rather wasteful in terms of memory:

1. When loading, it loads the entire file into memory and then construct the matrix. At the end of loading it has both the file and the matrix in memory. It could try loading the file iteratively (e.g. line by line) if the format allows.
2. The image matrix storage format is an array of arrays of arrays. Since arrays on each dimension allocated separately and for each allocated array there is some amount of memory (8-16 bytes normally) used for memory allocator internals, such a way of storing the matrix wastes a lot of memory. Try using a plain `std::vector<>`, e.g. ideally:

   ```
   struct RGB24 { uint8_t r, g, b; }; // one for each pixel format
   std::vector<RGB24> image(width * height); // allocate the matrix in one shot
   RGB24& pixel = image[row * width + col]; // get pixel image[row][col]
   ```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! So I won't be wasting any memory by using std::vector? And, will it be fast for my simple purpose?

Comment: @Bruce There should be no memory difference using a vector compared to an array.

Comment: Please don't encourage these kinds of "questions" by answering them :(